# Junit testing hazelcast based app in failure conditions

Tags: hazelcast

Is there a way by which I can configure hazelcast to fail in order to test how our application behaves when hazelcast fails.

Our application uses hazelcast. Certainly there will be issues with some nodes getting disconnected and so on...
We have code to handle such failures. How do we test this?

E.g: How do I junit test a scenario where my remote execution fails. Can I configure hazelcast to fail some remote execution calls for the purpose of testing?